# Simple method for $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^{2}}$ divide $lcm(1,2,\ldots,2n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, factorial, alternative-proof

The question is to prove that $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^{2}}$ divides $lcm(1,2,\ldots,2n+1)$.

This seems like it should be a simple question, but try as I might, I can't seems to find any way that does not involve a complicated argument using prime factorization.

So anyone know any simple obvious method to prove this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ethan: Can you elaborate more? (if that was meant to be a solution)

Comment: $$lcm(1,2,...,2n+1)=\prod_{p\leq 2n+1}p^{\lfloor{\log_p(2n+1)}\rfloor}$$

Comment: So it is a factorizing argument? I have a feeling that it will still end up being the complicated argument I mentioned. Or do you have a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'd this argument complicated, but one way to prove the statement goes as follows:

Let $v_p(k)$ be the [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) of prime $p$ in number $k$; i.e. the highest power of $p$ which divides $k$. There are a few observations we can make:

- Every $p$-th integer contributes one occurrence of $p$ into prime factorization of $(n!)$. Every $p^2$-th contributes an additional $p$ and so on. This can be summarized as the equality $$v_p(n!) = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^3}\right\rfloor + \ldots = \sum\limits_{e\geq 1} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^e}\right\rfloor$$
- The the sum is infinite, but only first $\left\lfloor \log_p(n)\right\rfloor$ terms are non-zero.
- Similar reasoning applies to 
  $$v_p((2n+1)!) = \sum\limits_{e\geq 1} \left\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{p^e}\right\rfloor$$ in which only first $\left\lfloor \log_p(2n+1)\right\rfloor$ terms are non-zero.
- For any positive integers $n$ and $k$, we have $$\left\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{k}\right\rfloor \leq 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right \rfloor+1$$
- $v_p(a/b) = v_p(a) - v_p(b)$, so $$v_p\left(\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}\right) = \sum\limits_{e\geq 1} \left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{p^e}\right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^e}\right\rfloor\right)\leq \lfloor\log_p(2n+1)\rfloor$$
- $v_p(\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)) = \max(v_p(a), v_p(b))$, so $$v_p(\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,2n+1)) = \left\lfloor log_p(2n+1)\right\rfloor$$
- Number $a$ divides number $b$ if and only if for all primes $p$, we have $v_p(a)\leq v_p(b)$. But we have just shown that this holds for $\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,2n+1)$; Q.E.D.

Comment: This is in fact the solution I had in mind. However, it's already seems somewhat complicated, but when I had to expand out the step to prove that $\lfloor{\frac{2n+1}{k}}\rfloor\leq 2\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\rfloor+1$ it became horribly complicated. You seems to take that as trivial, do you know any simply way to prove that?

Comment: Write $n$ as $n=k\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor+r$ with $0\leq r\leq (k-1)$. Then, $\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{k}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{2k\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor + 2r + 1}{k}\rfloor=2\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{2r+1}{k}\rfloor$. The expression in numerator of the second term does not exceed $(2k-1)$, so the second term does not exceed $1$.

Comment: OMG, that should have been obvious!!! It was so dumb of me. Thanks for the answer :D I will mark this one since it looks like noone is going to give a simpler one, even though it still look a bit long.